# Delete specific contents of file using Regex Expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

Consider that I have a data file storing rules in the following format:

```
//some header info
//more header info

//Rule: some_uuid_1234 
rule "name" 
 data
 data
 data
end

//Rule: some_uuid_5678 
rule "name2"
 data
 data
 data
end
```

Now, what I would like is to be able to either `read(id)` or `delete(id)` a rule given the ID number. My question therefore is, how could I select and delete a rule (perhaps using a regex expression), and then delete this specific rule from the file, without altering anything else.

Comment: How big is the file and how many rules does the file usually have ?

Comment: It is in fact user defined, i.e. I have another method such as `createRule(..)` - so it is not definite, could even be hundreds!

Comment: How fast should the read() and delete() operations be ? O(N) / O(1) etc.

Comment: It doesn’t matter, of course faster would be better, but even o(n) is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `<some_id>` in your select/delete function with the actual true ID number.

```
//Rule: <some_id>.+?rule.+?end
```

NOTE: Don't forget SingleLine option.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions I can think of and they have varied performance, so you can choose the one that suits you best.

## Index the file

You could write an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) for this rule file and keep it updated for any operation that modifies the file. Of course your word index will be limited to one file and the only words in it will be the unique UUIDs. You can use a RandomAccess file to quickly read() from a given offset. The delete() operation can overwrite the target rule until it encounters the word 'end'. This solution requires more work, but you can retrieve values instantly.

## Use a regex

You can alternatively read each line in the file and match it with a regex pattern that matches your rule UUID. Keep reading until you hit the 'end' of the rule and return it. A delete will involve over-writing the rule once you know the desired index. This solution is easy to write but the performance will suck. There is a lot of IO and it *could* become a bottleneck. (You could also load the entire file into memory and run a regex on the whole string, depending on how large the file / string is expected to be. This can get ugly real quick though.)

Whichever solution you choose you might also want to think about file level locks and how that affects CRUD operations. If this design has not been implemented yet, please consider moving the rules to a database.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use regular expressions to solve this particular problem - it would require loading the whole file in memory, processing it and rewriting it. That's not inherently bad, but if you have large enough files, a stream-based solution is probably better.

What you'd do is process your input file one line at a time and maintain a boolean value that:

- becomes `true` when you find a line that matches the desired rule's declaration header.
- becomes `false` when it's `true` and you find a line that matches `end`.

Discard all lines encountered while your boolean is set to `true`, write all other ones to a temporary output file (created, for example, with `File#createTempFile`).

For each line, if your boolean value is `true`, ignore it. Otherwise, write it to a temporary output file.

At the end of the process, overwrite your input file with your temporary output file using `File#renameTo`.

Note that this solution has the added advantage of being atomic: there is no risk for your input file to be partially written should an error occur in the middle of processing. It will either be overwritten entirely or not at all, which protects you against unexpected `IOException`s.

The following code demonstrates how you could implement that. It's not necessarily a perfect implementation, but it should illustrate the algorithm - lost somewhere in the middle of all that boilerplate code.

```
public void deleteFrom(String id, File file) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader;
    String         line;
    boolean        inRule;
    File           temp;
    PrintWriter    writer;

    reader = null;
    writer = null;
    try {
        // Streams initialisation.
        temp   = File.createTempFile("delete", "rule");
        writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(temp), "utf-8")));
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "utf-8"));
        inRule = false;

        // For each line in the file...
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // If we're parsing the rule to delete, we're only interested in knowing when we're done.
            if(inRule) {
                if(line.trim().equals("end"))
                    inRule = false;
            }

            // Otherwise, look for the beginning of the targetted rule.
            else if(line.trim().equals("rule \"" + id + "\""))
                inRule = true;

            // Normal line, we want to keep it.
            else
                writer.println(line);
        }
    }

    // Stream cleanup.
    finally {
        if(reader != null)
            reader.close();
        if(writer != null)
            writer.close();
    }

    // We're done, copy the new file over the old one.
    temp.renameTo(file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, this seems like a good solution for many reasons. For completion, could you kindly write a Java solution based on your explanation. I will then test/verify and accept your solution. Thnx!

Comment: @Larry, why don't you write it yourself?

Comment: @BartKiers Good point. Larry - You might want to seriously think about concurrency. What happens when 2 deletes() are requested at the same time ? How much disk IO will be provisioned for each write request ?